# Insert string after substring

Tags: c++, string

Maybe my title is weird :(

I have a problem here, I want to insert string into string.
First I input string that I want to insert, and input second string where the place where the previous stringis inserted

Here is my code

```
string a,b;
string str;

cin >> a >> b;
str.insert(b,a);
```

Here the example :

```
str = "ihaveadream";
a = "simple";
b = "ihavea";
```

Then the final result of str is:

```
str = "ihaveasimpledream";
```

In other words, the string `a` will be inserted after string `b`
How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the `insert` overloads take offset position in the string at which you wish to insert and a string you wish to insert. To find this position you could use `find` which will return the index of the beginning of the found string or `npos` if not found. If found you need to advance the length of your search string to get offset. In other words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::string a, b;
    std::string str = "ihaveadream";

    std::cin >> a >> b;
    size_t pos = str.find(b);

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        str.insert(pos + b.size(), a);

    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: Same like mine but without that conditional. Can you tell me what is the function?

Comment: @GeraldSihotang `std::string::npos` is basically -1 integer, and it indicates that no match was found. But because it is of type `size_t` which is unsigned, it is a very large number, something like `18446744073709551615`. If you try to insert at this position your program will crash and burn, hence the check.

Answer (score 2):

OK this is working

```
size_t pos; //position of string b
pos = str.find(b); 
str.insert(pos + b.size() , a);
```

Comment: Correct, but you need to make sure , the search is _valid_ .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::find(string&)` to search for the string `b` (the string you want to insert after).

After that, you can find the location to where string `a` needs to be added by adding the length of string `b` onto the position returned by `find`.

You can then use `std::string::substr` to split your big string `str` into two strings, from the beginning to the value returned by `find`, and from the value returned by `find` to the end.

Finally, you can concatenate your three strings in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you for the algorithm, I have find the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [***`std::string::find`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [***`std::string::insert`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)

Something like following:

```
if( auto pos = str.find(b) ; pos != std::string::npos ) 
   // Using C++17 construct, you could declare a variable outside as well for pre-C++17
{
    str.insert( pos + b.size() , a );
}
```

[`See here`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f4094de17d9fa03)